# How to figure out which Ruby gem has hijacked an ActiveRecord association method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, monkeypatching

Given this definition (using Rails 3.2.13 on Ruby 2.0.0-p195)...

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :recipe_foods, foreign_key: :food_id
```

.reset is not acting as documented (it's supposed to reset the @loaded flag but instead it's re-querying the database and returning results)...

```
2.0.0-p195 :037 > f = Food.last
  Food Load (1.6ms) ...
 => #<Food ...

2.0.0-p195 :038 > f.recipe_foods
  RecipeFood Load (9.4ms) ...
 => [#<RecipeFood ...

2.0.0-p195 :039 > f.recipe_foods.reset
  RecipeFood Load (10.0ms) ...
 => [#<RecipeFood ...
```

I suspect some other gem has hijacked the method, but this is what I get from .method ...

```
2.0.0-p195 :040 > f.recipe_foods.method(:reset).source_location
NameError: undefined method `reset' for class `Array'
```

How do I figure out what version of .reset is actually executing?

**UPDATE:**

When I try to call a non-existent method I get this chaos (in case that helps with the mystery):

```
2.0.0-p195 :052 > f.recipe_foods.snafu
NoMethodError: undefined method `snafu' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fdaef6315b0>

2.0.0-p195 :053 > f.recipe_foods.method(:snafu)
NameError: undefined method `snafu' for class `Array'
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that reset is actually a method on the AssociationProxy object, not the Array, which is why you're getting the undefined method. Rails 4 seems to be smarter about this:

```
> c = Company.first
> c.users.method(:find)
=> # <Method: ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_User(ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy)#find>
> c.users.method(:find).source_location
=> ["/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb", 140]
```

I'm not sure of the best solution here, but I'd see if any of the tools in [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use a debugger. `ruby-debug` worked up until Ruby 1.9; `byebug` works for Ruby 2.0.

Write a script with a debugger breakpoint right before the call that's breaking:

```
f = Food.last
rf = f.recipe_foods
byebug  # or debug
rf.reset
```

Then execute the script. The debugger will break right at before the call, which you can then step into to find out what code is actually being executed.